# How to add dictionary value to 'v-model' whith given key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add filterDataArray to my app in order to add parameters to my API request conditionally.

I've created filterData array like this:

```
filterData: [
     {key: 'name', value: ''},
     {key: 'surname', value: ''},
     {key: 'age', value: ''}
```

And now I want to bind my filter inputs to get something like this:

```
<v-text-field v-model="filterData.value.where(filterData.key == 'Name')"> 
</v-text-field>
```

and then pass filterData to APIController and build get request like this:

```
getfiltereddata(data) {
    var url = `/user?filtereddata=true`;
    data.forEach(element => {
    url = url + `&` + element.key + `=` + element.value;
}); //of course i have to check if valuie is not ''
```

Finall product should looks like this:

> /user?filtereddata=true&name=nameinput&surname=surnameinput&age=ageinput;

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: please explain more your use case

Comment: I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: i think you want to loop through filterData array and bind each object value to one input ?

Comment: Yes. 
If user add something to text field then specific entry in dictionary changes.
For exapmle if somebody enter "John" in name text field than dictionary entry sdhould looks like this:
 {key: 'name', value: 'John'}

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like iterating over the `filterData` array and bind each object to an input :

```
<template v-for="(data,index) in filterData">
    <v-text-field  v-model="filterData[index].value"> 
   </v-text-field>
</template>
```